# Why are dogs as pets considered haram?

Tags: sharia, hadith

I understand that dogs are considered haram, but what is the possible reason behind this?

I found the following quotes and others related to it might exists but I want to know what is the reasoning behind it?

> That the Messenger of Allah said: "Whoever acquires a dog - with the exception of a dog to guard livestock, a hunting dog, or a farm dog - each day a Qirat is deducted from his reward. [Abu Dawood [(ref)]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/17/1)
>
> I heard Allah's Apostle(P.B.U.H) saying; "Angels (of Mercy) do not enter a house wherein there is a dog or a picture of a living creature (a human being or an animal)." [Hadith - Bukhari 3:515 [(ref)]](http://muttaqun.com/dogs.html)

Comment: Daniel like I said in the above post i was asking why they are considered haram as pets, again the question that you just linked to no answer was given.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, dogs are not considered as haraam in Islam.

Islam gives permission to keep dogs for certain purposes, such as hunting, guarding livestock and protecting crops.

It is mentioned in Al-Quran

> And you would think them awake, while they were asleep. And We turned
>   them to the right and to the left, while their dog stretched his
>   forelegs at the entrance. If you had looked at them, you would have
>   turned from them in flight and been filled by them with terror.- [18:18](http://quran.com/18/18)

So dogs may be used for guards.

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], what has been made lawful for them. Say,
>   "Lawful for you are [all] good foods and [game caught by] what you
>   have trained of hunting animals which you train as Allah has taught
>   you. So eat of what they catch for you, and mention the name of Allah
>   upon it, and fear Allah ." Indeed, Allah is swift in account.- [5:4](http://quran.com/5/4)

Dogs may also be used for hunting, but they should be trained for it.

The only thing that it is considered haraam in Islam is to grew up the dog inside the house because of **its saliva**. The saliva of dogs often contains microscopic worms, science has shown. Dogs are not to be kept inside the house at all times. They should be kept outside.

But, take a look at the ayat that the dogs may be used for hunting. For hunting they should use their mouth and saliva. The hunted things(for ex, birds) are considered as pure and halal(we should cut them with the name of Allah). Since, they are trained(which may take about several months) especially for hunting.

You can tell now the saliva is not germfull and we can have them in our homes. No, keeping the hunting dogs is more harmful, we may have infants in our home and it may also affect our guests. we should keep the dogs outside like in a dog house.

Apart from all the above the main thing is, Allah(subh)'s love towards us is 70 times more than a mother's towards her children.

So, He knows which is good and which is bad to us.

Comment: Is there a reference for the 70 times more than a mother's?

Comment: @mezhang, see [Sahih Bukhari Volume 008, Book 073, Hadith Number 028](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/106-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2073.%20Good%20Manners%20and%20Form%20(Al-Adab)/7232-sahih-bukhari-volume-008-book-073-hadith-number-028.html), I can't find the hadith no. for 70 times better love but 70 is just a number, Allah loves His creations more than that.

Comment: It is the number that concerns me. If you don't have source about this number, I don't think it is appropriate to say so. I of course believe Allah's love for us is way greater than our parents.

Comment: Hi, where are the reference to saliva that you have just made?

Comment: @AzikAbdullah , I know this is splitting hairs in your eyes, but I think it is important that the hadith you quoted did not say love, but rather mercy.  Muhammad asked if the lady would throw her child into the fire, everyone said no, so Muhammad said, God is more merciful to his slaves...

You can be merciful even to one you do not love.

Answer (score 2):

As [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8807/3487) said dogs are not considered to be haram for hunt.

But below are the thing considered haram about dogs:

- eating dogs meat
- touching dogs feces
- keeping dogs in your house and living with it
- if a wet cloth contact with dog,you can't pray in that cloth and
  you should wash and clean it completely. Even if the dogs fur was on your
  cloth it is considered unclean and you should do the above mentioned

and one of the reason for that is because dogs and pigs have numerous microbes and are dirty.

The other reason is because they don't let angels come into your house.

Comment: Welcome to [Islam.SE](http://islam.stackexchange.com). Please try to provide references wherever and whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this matter needs a lot more consideration and study.Look into what are the pro's and con's of the nature of dogs.

To say that it is because of the saliva, there are 2 differing perspective, One is that dogs can be used for hunting and another is that if you see a dog lick a water from a bowl, you need to wash the bowl 7 times (1 with clay) if you're gonna used it for your own. Both are quotes from the hadith (based on what I've heard).Comes the question, is it really about the saliva?..if it is, then what are the natures of the germs?how does it transmit?..is it more dangerous to humans by direct contact or through water or is it that the dogs should be trained to just search or corner the animals so that the preys would not be bitten to death and we would be able to cut them in the name of God.

Then comes the reasons as to why we should not keep dogs in the house. Yes, it is true that a lot of people in this world has a dog as a pet and they still able to die of old age. BUT there are cases whereby a dog bites the hands that feeds them or attacked other passerby to death. Dogs are predators by blood. They hunt and attacked just like lions and wolves. But dogs are more proned to be kept as pet because they're considered less wild and tame able.But a predator is still a predator especially to those smaller than it. So, why take the risk. If you want to keep dogs as hunters or guards, then keep them outside. Again, there's also the whole saliva, dog poop and urine things.

But this is not to say that we should treat the dogs unfairly (I won't comment on the whole killing the dog issue, because i'm not even sure if it is true or not) because stories are told how a prostitue gained a place in heaven because she gave the thirsty dog a drink. The story gain a place in Islam teachings because the animal was a dog (God knows that it will be an issue) and it shows that all animals should be treated equally with kindness only then will God look kindly to us as well.

With pigs, i'm sure the reasons are clear why it is forbidden but with dogs, I believe there is a reason why for it to be mentioned as prohibited as well except for hunting, keepstock and guarding. That's the interesting thing about Islam and the words of God in the Quran. We are expected to study about it, to ask question why, why and why in order to find the answer. Perhaps a proper researched should be conducted if you really want to know. But if it is too bothersome, than you are welcome to do as you want and us Muslim will hold true to what we want. It's not really that big of an issue anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience questioning religious dogmas and asking for reasons and logic in them is not very productive endeavour.

They are as they are. They are to be upheld, not questioned and subjugated to rational thinking.

If you ask about religious reasons why dogs could be considered as haram, in article "Dogs in the Islamic Tradition and Nature" by Dr. Khaled Abou El Fadl, published in Encyclopedia of Religion and Nature, s.v., by Continuum International in 2004. it is stated:

> The essential point conveyed [...] is that dogs are impure animals, or, at least, that their saliva is a contaminant that voids a Muslim’s ritual purity. Hostility to dogs, not just as a source of physical but moral impurity, are further expressed in Prophetic reports claiming that angels, as God’s agents of mercy and absolution, will not enter a home that has a dog, or that the company of dogs voids a portion of a Muslim’s good deeds. Cultural biases against dogs as a source of moral danger reach an extreme point in reports that claim that Prophet commanded Muslims not trade or deal in dogs, and even to slaughter all dogs, except for those used in herding, farming, or hunting.

So, the mayor concern about dogs in Islam is not about their physical condition, health concerns or general cleanness, but about the ritual uncleanness and the effect of that to the religious life of a Muslim who comes in contact with the dog.

If you ask about rational, scientific reasons, amongst the few allegations that can be tested are numerous ones by Muslim scholars that dog's saliva is not just ritually impure, but a real health hazard. Modern science has shown that those concerns are not just false, but it is in fact shown that dog's saliva has antibacterial properties and that there are no particular scientific and therefore rational reasons for avoiding any contact with it if the dog is healthy, as is the case with any other animal or even humans.

*Source: "Antibacterial properties of saliva: Role in maternal periparturient grooming and in licking wounds" by Benjamin L. Hart & Karen L. Powell, Department of Physiological Sciences, School of Veterinary Medicine University of California, Davis, CA 95616 USA*

While avoiding dogs as social animals that could potentially spread a disease from one human to another might have been a valid reason 1400 years ago, in modern times, since we have modern medicine and sanitation, very little harm can come upon pet dog owner so there are no scientific reasons whatsoever to avoid dogs.

One exception is if a person is allergic to dogs. Allergies are caused by dander, saliva or urine of dogs, or by dust, pollen or other allergens that have been carried on the fur. Allergy to dogs is present in as much as 10 percent of the population, according to American College of Allergy, Asthma & Immunology.

In general, countless dogs lived along humans throughout our history and still are living in households all over the world without any (or neglectable) problems whatsoever.

**So, to conclude, if you ask for modern, rational and scientific reasons that confirm religious "reasoning" of Islam about having a dog as a pet, there are simply none!**

Comment: I still feel some considerations of the other dangers a dog may pose would be useful, certain Muslim scholars may have used the saliva as a possible danger but they were not the be all and end all of consideration so I feel the statement "there are simply none" is a significant overstatement

Comment: Tx Richard, I have corrected the flaw.

Comment: While this now is an answer of sorts I would still expect some downvotes. It still feels like an argument as to why Islam is wrong rather than actually attempting to answer the question. To put this in terms from programming in stack overflow (where we both have experience) an answer to the question "Why did Java's designers decide not to include goto statements" would not be an argument as to how great goto statements are. Your personal opinion should not feature in your answer

Comment: @Richard, well, you see, I do not possess any other opinions but my personal ones. Whose opinions should I use then? However, I backed my opinions with citations from other, more credible sources. I did mention the most credible religious reasons I could find as well as scientific ones. It is upon the asker to choose which one to value more. How come you don't object to "So, He knows which is good and which is bad to us." in other answer?

Comment: **They're asking you to provide them** [the reasons], thats the question. Proving a negative, that there are absolutely no arguments that could possibly support pet dogs being haram is a monumental task but it is the task you seem to have set for yourself. They're not asking you to pick a few reasons and show why they're false

Comment: I do not presume that I have the perfect answer. :) However, as I said, the only scientifically testable "reason" I could find was about saliva. And I cited a scientific view about dog's saliva which disproves religious one. I repeat, it is upon the asker to choose which "reason" he values the most. I do not claim that dogs are completely harmless, but I've never come across a muslim scholar claiming that dogs are dangerous animals either :D

Comment: Well you never mentioned that [dogs kill people](http://www.dogsbite.org/) which could have been a nice answer to this question. Regardless this is descending into debate which is forbidden: [scriptural reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35850/questions-regarding-subjectivity-and-extended-discussion)

Comment: People also kill people. A dog only attacks if seriously mistreated by the owner fyi!

Comment: @Richard Tingle so do tigers but are those forbidden to be kept as pets? There is no logic in Islam or any religion for that matter, either accept it in blind faith or don't. ALso pitbulls may kill people but do chihuahuas kill people? What does the Quran say about chihuahuas?