# Hadith for Allah's love 70 times better than mother's love

Tags: hadith, source-identification, prophet-muhammad, authenticity

I heard more times in bayans especially during Ramadhan that Allah(Sub)'s love is 70 times more than a mother's love to her children.

Is there any hadith with these wordings, ie, 70 times?

I searched over that and found some hadiths below.

> Narated By Abu Huraira : I heard Allah's Apostle saying, Allah divided
>   Mercy into one-hundred parts and He kept its ninety-nine parts with
>   Him and sent down its one part on the earth, and because of that, it's
>   one single part, His creations are Merciful to each other, so that
>   even the mare lifts up its hoofs away from its baby animal, lest it
>   should trample on it." - [Sahih Bukhari.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/106-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2073.%20Good%20Manners%20and%20Form%20%28Al-Adab%29/7231-sahih-bukhari-volume-008-book-073-hadith-number-029.html)
>
> Narated By 'Umar bin Al-Khattab : Some Sabi (i.e. war prisoners,
>   children and woman only) were brought before the Prophet and behold, a
>   woman amongst them was milking her breasts to feed and whenever she
>   found a child amongst the captives, she took it over her chest and
>   nursed it (she had lost her child but later she found him) the Prophet
>   said to us, "Do you think that this lady can throw her son in the
>   fire?" We replied, "No, if she has the power not to throw it (in the
>   fire)." The Prophet then said, "Allah is more merciful to His slaves
>   than this lady to her son."- [Sahih Bukhari.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/106-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2073.%20Good%20Manners%20and%20Form%20%28Al-Adab%29/7232-sahih-bukhari-volume-008-book-073-hadith-number-028.html)

But, I can't find the hadith with exact number `70`.

Surely, Allah(sub)'s love and mercy encompasses all things.-[Al-Quran:7:156](http://quran.com/7/156)

I need to know the hadith source identification for the 70 times better love. It will be useful to say this to friends with authentic references.

Comment: I did not know that love is well-defined enough for us to do arithmetic on it.

Comment: @mezhang, this is [your](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/why-are-dogs-as-pets-considerd-haram/8807#comment17044_8807) question :)

Comment: muslim , why are u saying/commenting that number 70 is not found in the stated hadiths when there is a hadith saying the number 70??? i need the answer ,.u confused me

Comment: @Abdulkarim, in [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/20/2), it is mentioned that our prophet seeking Allah's pardon seventy times. But the question is about the love of Allah better than 70 times of mother's love. Don't confuse brother, our Almighty's love is greater than all.

Comment: In Saheeh Muslim it is narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah has one hundred parts of mercy, of which He sent down one between the jinn, mankind, the animals and the insects, by means of which they are compassionate and merciful to one another, and by means of which wild animals are kind to their offspring. And Allah has kept back ninety-nine parts of mercy with which to be merciful to His slaves of the Day of Resurrection.” 

(Muslim, al-Tawbah, 6908)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                 بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

Many hadiths are informing us about the Almighty Allah's mercy toward his slaves. I found the following hadith in a book entitled "Understanding the Month of Glory Lessons on the Month of Ramadhan":

> Allah loves the best of His creations, the human being. One day the
>   Holy Prophet (S) was walking with his companions when he saw a mother
>   bird with her babies in a nest. The mother bird was feeding the small
>   ones some worms. So tender and gentle were her actions, that the
>   companions were awe-struck at this display of love. The Prophet (S)
>   smiled and said, "Are you surprised at the love this mother bird has
>   for her babies? Let me inform you that **Allah loves His creatures, the
>   human beings seventy times more than this mother**!"

But I didn't find the reference from which author has brought this hadith.

Answer (score 2):

There are many hadiths that mention the [number 70](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/20/2). Its not the actual quantitive measure but more, a figure of speech in arab (and other) cultures to show something that is done repeatedly or something excessive.

Comment: We have similar phrases like "hundreds of times" and "dozens of them."

Comment: number 70 is not found in the stated hadiths, not a correct answer.

Comment: Second one from the top... "I heard the Messenger of Allah saying, "I swear by Allah that I seek Allah's Pardon and turn to Him in repentance more than seventy times a day." [Al-Bukhari].

Answer (score -2):

> Allah loves the best of His creations, the human being. One day the Holy Prophet (S) was walking with his companions when he saw a mother bird with her babies in a nest. The mother bird was feeding the small ones some worms. So tender and gentle were her actions, that the companions were awe-struck at this display of love. The Prophet (S) smiled and said, "Are you surprised at the love this mother bird has for her babies? Let me inform you that Allah loves His creatures, the human beings seventy times more than this mother!"

@Muslim here is the hadith , tell me when you see this hadith and accept it (I was talking about this hadith mentioned here) (70 mothers)

and no hadith is inauthentic because allah said:

> Indeed, it is We who sent down the Qur'an and indeed, We will be its guardian. http://quran.com/15/9

and in another verse:

> whatever the prophet says, is a verse from allah

Comment: -1, what is the source of the 2nd verse ? and the scholars of hadith would disagree with your statement of "no inauthentic hadith"

Answer (score -2):

As per my research there is no such hadith ("Allah loves His servants 70 times more") in Sahih Bukhari; Allah knows best.  I, however, can't comment on other books or the authenticity of this hadith since I am not a scholar of ahadith.

Comment: This really isn't very useful as an answer; as written, it looks like you're more interested in arguing about *ulum-al-hadith* than in actually [writing a good answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please note that we are not a typical Internet forum, and *especially* not a forum for arguing and debate (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22). The "Post Your Answer" field is for those posts that *directly answer the question asked*, and is expected to be complete and focussed on that question.