# Hadith: Allah being more merciful to His slaves than a mother to her child

Tags: hadith

[From sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin/introduction/418)

> Some prisoners were brought to Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) amongst whom
> there was a woman who was running (searching for her child). When she
> saw a child among the captives, she took hold of it, pressed it
> against her belly and gave it a suck. Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Do
> you think this woman would ever throw her child in fire?" We said, "By
> Allah, she would never throw the child in fire." Thereupon Messenger
> of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Allah is more kind to his slave than this woman is
> to her child".

[Also from sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/30)

> Some Sabi (i.e. war prisoners, children and woman only) were brought
> before the Prophet (ﷺ) and behold, a woman amongst them was milking
> her breasts to feed and whenever she found a child amongst the
> captives, she took it over her chest and nursed it (she had lost her
> child but later she found him) the Prophet said to us, "Do you think
> that this lady can throw her son in the fire?" We replied, "No, if she
> has the power not to throw it (in the fire)." The Prophet (ﷺ) then
> said, "Allah is more merciful to His slaves than this lady to her
> son."

I am a bit confused. Is the mother in question breast-feeding her own child, or other children? And I remember hearing some other versions of this hadith, where the mother was desperately looking for her child,and when she found the child, she started to breast-feed, and the Messenger of Allah said what he said. Which version is considered to be more reliable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hadith for Allah's love 70 times better than mother's love](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8949/hadith-for-allahs-love-70-times-better-than-mothers-love)

Comment: No. And I was aware of that.