# Is it allowed to deal with dogs as a veterinarian and what are the rules in regards to this?

Tags: sharia, profession, dogs

I am a student in high school and have been considering becoming a veterinarian for some time now. It has occurred to me that if I were to become a vet I would most likely have to work with dogs. Is this allowed?

What are the rules I should follow if so?

If possible add an ayat or a hadith to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this allowed?

Yes no doubt.  Dogs are a creation of Allah and treating them, or any animal, with kindness that is due right upon them unless prevented otherwise.

The Prophet said =

> أَنَّ رَجُلاً رَأَى كَلْبًا يَأْكُلُ الثَّرَى مِنَ الْعَطَشِ، فَأَخَذَ
> الرَّجُلُ خُفَّهُ فَجَعَلَ يَغْرِفُ لَهُ بِهِ حَتَّى أَرْوَاهُ،
> فَشَكَرَ اللَّهُ لَهُ فَأَدْخَلَهُ الْجَنَّةَ
>
> "A man saw a dog eating
> mud from thirst. The man took a shoe with water and kept on pouring
> for the dog till it quenched its thirst. So Allah approved of his deed
> and made him to enter Paradise."

[[Sahih al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/39)

> بَيْنَمَا كَلْبٌ يُطِيفُ بِرَكِيَّةٍ كَادَ يَقْتُلُهُ الْعَطَشُ، إِذْ
> رَأَتْهُ بَغِيٌّ مِنْ بَغَايَا بَنِي إِسْرَائِيلَ، فَنَزَعَتْ مُوقَهَا
> فَسَقَتْهُ، فَغُفِرَ لَهَا بِهِ
>
> "While a dog was going round a well and was about to die of thirst, an
> Bani Israeli prostitute saw it and took off her shoe and watered it. So
> Allah forgave her because of that good deed."

[[Sahih al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/134)

There's a gross culturally influenced misconception that somehow dogs are evil or dirty animals.  However, this has absolutely no *Quranic/hadith* backing whatsoever.

So as a vet, you do your best to improve the lives of animals, including dogs *InshaAllah*

Answer (score 1):

Islamically, there is no harm in having a dog unless you consider it as a pet.

and dogs are just like any other animals. So treating them is permissible.

*Somehow related:* *[Why are dogs as pets considered haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/why-are-dogs-as-pets-considered-haram)*